# How to create form that groups objects of one entity according to one of the fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities: **Contracts** and **Plots**:

DzialkiBundle\Entity\Contracts:
     type:                  entity
     table:                 Contracts

```
 oneToMany:
      plots:
           targetEntity:     Plots
           mappedBy:          contract
           cascade:          [persist]
```

DzialkiBundle\Entity\Plots:
     type:                  entity
     table:                 Plots

```
 fields:
       place:
            type:             integer

manyToOne:
      contract:
           targetEntity:     Contracts
           inversedBy:     plots
           joinColumn:
                name:     contract_id
                referencedColumnName:     id
```

And I am creating a form for Contracts entity. In this form I would like to insert also a possibility to choose (via select element) the Plots entities.

But, to make it harder, I need to break the Plots entities into groups.
They have to be grouped by one of the fields (place). When I choose the place (via another select element), the Plots that have this value of place have to be loaded into the other select element (via ajax) to give opportunity to choose from.

Now, I know how to do the html/javascript part of it. But I am not sure how to implement ContractsType and PlotsType classes in order to have this "grouping" working how I would like to.

I know how to add dynamically another select element based on what the user submitted or what currently on the db. But I still don't know how to group the PlotsType by its field (I don't want select1, select2... elements, I would rather like to it generate collection of select elements, grouped automatically by the place field).

I think what makes it hard for me is that the place field is in the Plots entity, not in Contracts. So I can't check the value of place when I don't know the Plots object.

Any ideas how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "group by the place field" you mean only the plots relevant to the contract or visually grouped?

Comment: Actually both. From among the plots that are linked to the contract, I want to group them by their place field.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using form events. It is defined here in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

The code looks like below. (in its example, the position field depends of the sport field.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sport', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'App\Entity\Sport',
                'placeholder' => '',
            ));
        ;

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null) {
            $positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getAvailablePositions();

            $form->add('position', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Position',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $positions,
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSport());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the dynamic form generation is not the hard part for me. I have just clarified a bit my problem.

Comment: You would have to add your custom query grouping the places instead of `$positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getAvailablePositions();`

Comment: Problem is that this will only create one select element, within which the Plots are visually grouped. I don't need that. I need number of select elements, each one for the different value of place field from Plots entity.